# How to Insert Primary Value (PK) to Related Table (FK)

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having trouble from Inserting 1 Primary Value (Increment) of TABLE to another TABLE (Foreign Key)

Table 1 has the Primary key of Student Number; if i enter values for last and first name  from TABLE 1 then the student number will automatically giving it's own value because of Increment, and else if i entered from TABLE 2, I want the value of Student Number from TABLE i will increment even the value of Last and First name if TABLE 1 is NULL

## Table 1

---

### (PK)Student_# | Last_Name | First_Name

...........1...........|........a..........|..........b.......

...........2...........|........c..........|..........b.......

## Table 2

---

### (FK)Student_# | Year_Level | Section

...........NULL................|..........2nd Year......|.....C1 .........

...........NULL................|..........3rd Year......|.....D1 .........

## Needed

---

### (FK)Student_# | Year_Level | Section

..............1...................|..........2nd Year......|.....C1 .........

..............2...................|..........3rd Year......|.....D1 .........

Comment: this is some what confusing... you want auto increment in table 1 and 2 both and then why you give pk/fk???

Comment: It looks like your other question is going to be closed as duplicate. But in future, if you want to change your question, use the `edit` link. Don't post a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you need a primary key with an identity seed on table2 and also a foreign key to the student table:

```
(PK/Identity) Table2ID | (FK)Student_# | Year_Level | Section
```

This way you can insert the student_# when you insert the record into table 2 and also be able to give each row in table2 a unique identifier

```
CREATE TABLE Table2
(
 Table2ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
,Student_# INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Table1(Student_#)
,Year_Level NVARCHAR(255) --Use whatever data type you need
,Section NVARCHAR(255) --Use whatever data type you need
)
```

I have assumed you are using sql server as you have not specified in your question. You may need to change this query for a different RDBMS.